# sqlsrv_connect: Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xampp

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 on machine-1 from PHP code on another machine-2.
I am using PHP 5.4.7, XAMPP 1.8.1 and I have copied the sql server dlls into PHP/ext folder and modified the php.ini file.

Now, when I try to connect to SQL server I am getting following error.

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )

My PHP code is as follows -

```
<?php
//phpinfo(); 
$server = "sql server\express,1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$uid="username";
$pwd="password";
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database"=>"rod_prd_tmart");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo) ;

if($conn) 
{
   echo "Connection established.\n";
} else
{
   echo "Connection could not be established in this text.\n";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: download and install the driver from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 and edit php.ini. copying sql server dlls don't work

Comment: Thanks Bansi.Actually I have downloaded and installed the sql server drivers and edited the php.ini file alrdy.

Comment: have you also restarted your web server? your code looks fine

Comment: Tip: `print_r()` output's has carriage returns. You'll see them if you use the "View Source" feature of your browser.

Comment: I suppose you've already done it but you don't say it explicitly. Have you installed **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client**?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, SQL server database resides on another machine-2. Does PHP Code and SQL server database need to be on same machine?

Comment: One more question, my SQL server version is 2008. But do i need to install SQL Server 2012 native client for 64 bit OS? PLease let me know.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest if I would need to install MS SQL Server Native CLient 2012 or 2008? Other than that Do I need to install full SQL Studio or just Native Client as I am not sure how it will work if I install only Native Client?  PLease help.

Comment: @user2742601 - 1) Yes, SQL Server supports networking; it isn't Access. 2) The 32/64-bit thing has nothing to do with SQL Server versions. 3) The error clearly tells you to install Native Client 2012—what makes you think that's wrong? —— Two general rules I always follow: 1) Use the latest version of everything unless you have a specific reason (for instance, SQLSRV does *not* support PHP/5.5 yet so you need to use PHP/5.4). 2) Read the error messages and try their recommendations first.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) for more flexibility:

```
//$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname;", $username, $password);  // works with proper driver for PHP.
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname;", $username, $password);  // works with proper driver for ODBC and PHP ODBC.
```

I could not get the first line to work due to weird compiler version incompatibilities, but the second one worked fine after installing [Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

PHP Version 5.3.0 has built-in ODBC support, according to `php.ini`, but here that still lists an active `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll`