# PHP SQL Server Couldn't connect

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to ask you about how to connect to MSSQL Server 2005 using PHP?

I got error like this :

> Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access
>   the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native
>   Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This
>   extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access
>   the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native
>   Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] =>
>   IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source
>   name not found and no default driver specified ) )

and here is my PHP code :

```
<?php
    $serverName = "192.168.183.249\MSSQLSERVER, 1542"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber default is 1433)
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SEI_AproCS", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

Please help to advice.

THanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589942/php-to-sql-server-connection-gives-drive-error

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install driver from this link
[PHP Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx)

You can follow this link for tutorial
[PHP MSSQL Tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

An other option is to connect to mssql using DSN , 
and this easy way you just to enable mssql extension in php

And follow this link to create DSN [Create DSN in windows](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1471/sql-server-dsn-and-odbc-configuration/)

Also follow this link to connect using php and DSN
[Connect php using DSN](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php)

Comment: I just followed that step and still can't connect :(

Comment: is mssql local at your machine ?
and do you have to use this method ?

Comment: I using php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll, not mssql. I have tried using mssql but for PHP 5.4 cant

Comment: @Kongkow see the new edits , and don't forget to install mssql server at your local machine if you use local mssql database .

Answer (score 1):

To connect with sql server you need to add dll file for sql server in the directory

```
wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059):

```
//$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname;", $username, $password);  // works with proper driver for PHP.
$pdo = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname;", $username, $password);  // works with proper driver for ODBC and PHP ODBC.
```

I could not get the first line to work due to weird compiler version incompatibilities, but the second one worked fine after installing [Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

PHP Version 5.3.0 has built-in ODBC support, according to `php.ini`, but that still lists an active `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` here.

Answer (score 0):

You instal driver. ODBC

- msodbcsql_x64.msi #System Operation 63
- msodbcsql_x86.msi #System Operation 86/32

link download
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

good luck